# Can I remove frost from frozen chicken breasts and re-package?

Tags: chicken, storage-method, freezing

I bought a large package of chicken breast several weeks ago. Usually we break down the bag and package in food saver bags to keep frost at a minimum. For some reason we didn't do it this time. I just went to get a few for tonight and noticed it's all iced up inside. Can I run them under warm water to remove the ice and re-package them in our food saver bags now or is it too late? Anyone know of any other tricks? They don't seem freezer burned yet.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend just cooking them sooner rather than later. If you had to do anything, I'd consider cracking & brushing off the surface ice without thawing them, then vacuum sealing them ... but still try to use them quickly.

If the texture is a little off, or the flavor a little lacking, you can always use the rest in either soup or a casserole, where the texture isn't as much of an issue and there are other flavors to help compensate.